# Easy way to get START_TIME from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION

Tags: spring-batch

A job in Spring-batch will save status on the job in the table `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`. Is there an easy way (beside reading the column `START_TIME` in the table itself) to get the start time of the job from a Step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the idea to get access to the job execution from the step execution. For example:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                @Override
                public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                    JobExecution jobExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution();
                    System.out.println("hello world! Job started at: " + jobExecution.getStartTime());
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }
            })
            .build();
}
```